# How to recognize characters in an image using OCR without specifying any language?

Tags: open-source, ocr

Is there a way to recognize characters in an image using OCR without specifying any (human) languages?

Note: I have a set of characters (with a specific font) in an image. The content that consists of these characters in meaningless (from a language point of view) like a car no.

Is there a way to (programmatically or by using a product; open-source is preferred) recognize them?

Comment: Based on your comment, I think you mean a automobile registration (or license) plate number. That is an extremely well studied problem with significant literature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_number_plate_recognition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [Tesseract-OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)? 
As of version 3, tesseract can work well with left-to-right languages. 
You can also [train tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3).

I have not used it myself but if you have a limited set of characters you want to recognize -- from different languages, maybe you can modify the training procedure to suit your needs.